# MS Excel Lookup to match a range

Tags: excel

Good morning,

I wish to automate the 'action list' on a spreadsheet.

Currently, column B contains numeric values, the type of which is described in column A. I would like Column C to do this:
1. Look for a specific word in Column A
2. Based upon the result of (1.), look at a table of values
3. Find where the value in Column B falls within the table range
4. Using the position in the range, return the action

For example, if I have 3 tables called Red, White and Blue, then typing 'Big White Light' in Colum A would point to the range of values in table 'White' only.
The numeric value in column B would then finds it's position within the range available in table 'White' and return the 'Action'

[image]

Comment: Your example makes no sense.

Comment: If the word White appears in a cell in column A, then the value in column B of the same row should only be checked against the range of values in the table named 'White' and return the action accordingly in column C of the same row.

Comment: Explain where *Poor* comes from. Explain how negative numbers work. Explain how *61* is between *31* and *40*.

Comment: Your range of values in those 3 *tables* (by the way, those are **not** tables, they are just ranges), are positive (i.e white is 0-20,21-30,31-40), but value of `Medium White Heart` is negative, it's -25. Also, ¿Is there any max and min? Also, please, post what you have tried.

Comment: OH, I see now line that says **all values are absolute**. That explains how negative numbers work. What about rest of questions?

Comment: Thank you Foxfire, yes all values are absolute and, theoretically there is no max, although in practice values in excess of 100 are unlikely. I can get the lookup to find a single match, but not to do the multiple search required to point at the table, sorry range, relevant to the 'keyword' found in column A.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, If all numbers are absolute then why is *Blue -3* returning *Average* instead of *Good*?

Comment: @user11121185 Yep, good one. Let's see what OP have to say

Comment: Because, user11121185, I am human, therefore, prone to error.

Comment: Small white glove should return Stop, as any value above the range of values defaults to the nearest availble option in Excel, is that not true?

Comment: Thanks Jerry - correction pending!!

Comment: Yes Foxfire, Blue -3 should indeed return Good

Comment: What about *Blue 35*? Is that *Bad* or *Stop*?

Comment: [Edit] your question to show your corrections. Don't use the comments as some sort of editorial mockup.

Comment: @user11121185 Blue 35 should be Bad, I have tried to attach a corrected copy of the illustration, but it seems I am not worthy

Comment: Questions: 1) Is using vba/macro an option? 2) re the “tables” where you look the information for always at the same location? 3) are those “tables” fixed? Or could they have more “ranges” to look info for in the future?

Comment: You can put only the image link like when you first asked the question. Someone will change it afterwards

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, thanks, the "tables" are always in the same location. If the values were updated, that would only be by manual intervention. The ranges in each "table" are fixed. As you can tell, I'm not savvy enough to use VBA so I fear I wouldn't learn from a posted solution, however, as I have used formulas in Excel, albeit fairly rudimentary stuff, I should be able to follow the suggested solution.

Comment: @Jerry thank you, keeping editorial to a minimum!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for VLookup to work you have to change the "tables" ranges (columns E, G, I) to just numbers (lower limit of each range) and use a cell's custom format to show them as you want [see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-text-and-numbers-a32c8e0e-90a2-435b-8635-5dd2209044ad).

[image]

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(LOWER($E$1);LOWER(A2)))=FALSE;VLOOKUP(ABS(B2);$E$2:$F$4;2;TRUE);IF(ISERR(FIND(LOWER($G$1);LOWER(A2)))=FALSE;VLOOKUP(ABS(B2);$G$2:$H$5;2;TRUE);IF(ISERR(FIND(LOWER($I$1);LOWER(A2)))=FALSE;VLOOKUP(ABS(B2);$I$2:$J$5;2;TRUE);"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retype the numbers into your lookup tables and use custom number formatting to show the number ranges. For example, type `21` into E3 then apply a custom number format of `0-3\0` to make it look like `21-30`. Or type `71` into I5 and give it a custom number format of `>=0` to make it look like `>=71`.

If you do that then you can treat the number ranges as real numbers.

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(ABS(B2), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("white", A2)), E:F,  IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue", A2)), G:H, I:J)), 2, TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks @user11121185, your solution works for white and blue but not red. Do I just nest another IF statement condition for Red? Just realised that the last part of the formula uses RED as the previous conditions have not been matched.